# Error en la autentificación por separar la entidad Usuario en dos: Usuario y Rol

Tags: symfony, symfony4

En un principio tenía dentro de la entidad `Usuario` sus respectivos roles y se autentificaba al sistema de manera normal.

Pero con fines de diseño lo separé a dos entidades `Usuario` y `Rol` que  tienen una relación de muchos a muchos (*many to many*)  y ahora ya no puede autentificarse al sistema porque los roles están en la entidad `Rol` y me muestra el siguiente error:

> Type error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/coresis/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Hola OmarAlavi, gracias por traducir la pregunta. No sé de symfony, así que no sé si podré servirte de ayuda. El error pone que el constructor espera un array pero le estás pasando un objeto, creo que podría ser interesante que añadas el código del constructor y la parte desde donde se llama.

Comment: Este el codigo:

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que das muy pocas pistas, creo que puede ser lo siguiente, el en proceso de autenticación contra Symfony tienes que decirle de donde sacar los roles de cada entidad usuario, lo que tienes que crear es un Authenticator, hay un ejemplo que seguramente te servirá si es eso:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

**Tengo otras idea**:

Antes de esto tengo una idea: cambia tu método getRoles (espero este en la clase usuario) y que retorne un array de la siguiente forma:

```
['ROL1', 'ROL2', ...]
```

Puede que como symfony busca ese método para intentar llenar los roles te baste con eso.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

esto te sucede porque lo que devuelve la relación `ManyToMany` es un `ArrayCollection` te recomiendo que cambies tu método **get** para que puedas gestionar los roles como elementos de un `array`

```
/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function getRoles()
  {
    $roles = [];

    foreach ($this->roles as $rol) {
      $roles = array_merge($roles, $rol->getRol());
    }

    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
  }
```

#### Propuesta

Propongo que utilices Grupos y no roles, la relación entre Usuario y Grupo donde los grupos contendrán los roles te permitirán un nivel de abstracción mucho mayor y la gestión de tu proyecto sera más eficiente

### User

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Entity;
    
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    
    /**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
    * @ORM\Table(name="app_user")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="user.email.email_exist")
    */
    class User implements UserInterface
    {
      const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
      /**
      * @ORM\Id()
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      */
      private $id;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
      * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.name.not_blank")
      * @Assert\Length(min="3", minMessage="user.name.min_length", max="25",maxMessage="user.name.max_length")
      */
      private $name;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=35)
      * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.lastname.not_blank")
      * @Assert\NotNull(message="user.name.not_null")
      * @Assert\Length(min="3", minMessage="user.lastname.min_length", max="35",maxMessage="user.lastname.max_length")
      */
      private $lastname;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
      * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.email.not_blank")
      * @Assert\NotNull(message="user.email.not_null")
      * @Assert\Email(message="user.email.email_message")
      * @Assert\Length(max="70",maxMessage="user.name.max_length")
      */
      private $email;
    
      /**
      * @var string The hashed password
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      */
      private $password;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
      */
      private $active;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
      */
      private $registrationDate;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
      */
      private $lastLogin;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
      */
      private $passwordRequest;
    
      /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Group")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_group",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
      private $groups;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="array")
      */
      private $roles;
    
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
      */
      private $token;
    
      public function __construct()
      {
        $this->active = false;
        $this->roles = array();
      }

      **getter y setter**
    
      
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function addRole($role)
      {
        $role = strtoupper($role);
        if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
          return $this;
        }
    
        if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
          $this->roles[] = $role;
        }
    
        return $this;
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function getRoles()
      {
        $roles = $this->roles;
    
        foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
          $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
        }
    
        // we need to make sure to have at least one role
        $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;
    
        return array_unique($roles);
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function hasRole($role)
      {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function removeRole($role)
      {
        if (false !== $key = array_search(strtoupper($role), $this->roles, true)) {
          unset($this->roles[$key]);
          $this->roles = array_values($this->roles);
        }
    
        return $this;
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function setRoles(array $roles)
      {
        $this->roles = array();
    
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
          $this->addRole($role);
        }
    
        return $this;
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function getGroups()
      {
        return $this->groups ?: $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function getGroupNames()
      {
        $names = array();
        foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
          $names[] = $group->getName();
        }
    
        return $names;
      }
    
      /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
      public function hasGroup($name)
      {
        return in_array($name, $this->getGroupNames());
      }
    
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function addGroup(Group $group)
       {
           if (!$this->getGroups()->contains($group)) {
               $this->getGroups()->add($group);
           }
    
           return $this;
       }
    
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function removeGroup(Group $group)
       {
           if ($this->getGroups()->contains($group)) {
               $this->getGroups()->removeElement($group);
           }
    
           return $this;
       }
    
    }
```

### Group

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_group")
 */
class Group
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($name="DEFAULT", $roles = ['ROLE_USER'])
    {
      $this->name = $name;
      $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    **getter y setter**

    public function getRoles(): ?array
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addRole($role)
    {
        if (!$this->hasRole($role)) {
            $this->roles[] = strtoupper($role);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->roles, true);
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function removeRole($role)
   {
       if (false !== $key = array_search(strtoupper($role), $this->roles, true)) {
           unset($this->roles[$key]);
           $this->roles = array_values($this->roles);
       }

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function setRoles(array $roles)
   {
       $this->roles = $roles;

       return $this;
   }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```